# How can I play audio from a URL in the client-side ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html5-audio

I am creating a page in an ASP.NET (.NET Framework Version 4.0, ASP.NET Version 4.7) web application and I need to be able to play audio from a server

The URL is like this: http://xx.xx.xxx.x/.global/call_recording_archive/download.php?file=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-all.mp3 but I can't work out any way that I can get this to stream to the audio player in the browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is by using javascript and the DOM api you can create a hidden [audio node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) and call the play method in javascript.

### Step 1

You can do this dynamically in javascript or simply place a hidden audio node in your html

```html
<audio id="audioPlayer" style="display:none" autoplay=false>
  <source id="audioSrc" src="foo.wav" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element. 
</audio>
```

### Step 2

After receiving your stream you can set the source of the audio element

```js
var audioSrc = document.getElementById("audioSrc")
audioSrc.setAttribte("src","http://xx.xx.xxx.x/.global/call_recording_archive/download.php?file=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-all.mp3");
```

### Step 3

Now that you have an audio element you can call the `play` method on that element in your browser

```js
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("audioPlayer")
audioPlayer.play()
```

### Additional Notes

There are other methods eg `stop` , `pause`

You can even have more control over the `AudioContext` have a look at this article

- details about the web audio api - https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/fr/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API
- second article  - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Comment: Thanks very much for this. The problem I'm having is that this audio is coming from a table which is being populated using. NET, would there be a way to allow the audio to play from this dynamically-inserted URL?